# Innerwidth and innerheight calculation using javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, variables

My code is only working inside a setInterval() or settimeout() function. I don't know how to do it using a basic javascript function. I don't want to use the setInterval function and the time is 0 ms, which is why I need to get the values before anything shows up on screen. Help me out - how to make it work without those functions.

JAVASCRIPT

```
   setInterval(function()
   
   {       
       if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 215px)").matches) 
       {
           const mainwidth = window.innerWidth * 1.0;
           const mainheight = window.innerHeight * 1.0;
           document.getElementById("show-logo").style.setProperty('--set-mainwidth', mainwidth + "px");
           document.getElementById("show-logo").style.setProperty('--set-mainheight', mainheight + "px");
       }

   }, 0);
```

This code works well but I don't want to use setInterval or setTimeout. So I tried the code below but not working. How can I fix this and make it fast without setting any millisecond time..?

JAVASCRIPT

```
   var loadcheck = initialload();  
   function initialload()  
   {       
       if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 215px)").matches) 
       {
           const mainwidth = window.innerWidth * 1.0;
           const mainheight = window.innerHeight * 1.0;
           document.getElementById("show-logo").style.setProperty('--set-mainwidth', mainwidth + "px");
           document.getElementById("show-logo").style.setProperty('--set-mainheight', mainheight + "px");
       }
   }
```

Comment: You define loadcheck before the function so it is undefined. Call it after the function.

Comment: The `setInterval()` function/part of your code – is it used for testing if the window changes in size?

Comment: Not working even putting it after the function. Any other solution?

Comment: You could use ``document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { <code of your function initialload()> });``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example I defined a function `updateLogo()` that performs the update of the two CSS properties/variables. Using event listeners on both `DOMContentLoaded` on `document` and on `resize` on `window` the function will be called.

If the purpose of the `setInterval()` was to update the properties when the window is resized, using the event listener is mush better.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', updateLogo);
window.addEventListener('resize', updateLogo);

function updateLogo() {
  if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 215px)").matches) {
    const mainwidth = window.innerWidth * 1.0;
    const mainheight = window.innerHeight * 1.0;
    document.getElementById("show-logo").style.setProperty('--set-mainwidth', mainwidth + "px");
    document.getElementById("show-logo").style.setProperty('--set-mainheight', mainheight + "px");
  }
  console.log(document.getElementById("show-logo").outerHTML);
}
```

```html
<div id="show-logo"></div>
```

Comment: Your code is nice and working like the same as before. But I have this div that contains a word website's name which is flickering once before showing up into its calculated position. `<span id="elo-load">elo</span><span id="my-load">MY</span><span id="melo-load">melo</span>` This is under that show-logo div. I'm using `calc(var(--set-mainwidth)*0.392);` for setting the left, top position and font-size. But for first 10 ms the font-size appears very small at left : 0px; like position. After 10 ms it shows up in middle proper position. Looks like a flicker. Any way to make it even faster?

Comment: @SoumyaRoy it is really hard to tell what is wrong, but it sounds like too many things are happening or that the wrong properties are set. Do whatever you can to simplify your code. Instead of using position, maybe you could use flex box or grid. Anyway, open another question if you can narrow down the issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for a better solution ...